# Recursion over a dictionary for epsilon closure stops working when list is passed in

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am currently making a function for epsilon closure in python. I am using recursion to run through each possible transition in an NFA using epsilon. My inputs for the function is a dictionary formatted as:

```
tf2 = {('q0','a') : 'q1', ('q1','eps') : ['q2', 'q3'], ('q3','eps') : 'q0', ('q2','a') : 'q4', ('q4','eps') : 'q3'}
```

Where the key is a 2-tuple (current-state, input) and the value is the resulting-state.

In this case, the transitions I am trying to close are the ones where `'eps'` is the second part of the key.

The issue I am running into is whenever a value that contains a list is passed in (like in the `('q1','eps') : ['q2', 'q3']` entry) my recursion fails with a `"unhashable type: 'list'"` exception.

The code I have now is as follows:

```
tf2 = {('q0','a') : 'q1', ('q1','eps') : ['q2', 'q3'], ('q3','eps') : 'q0', ('q2','a') : 'q4', ('q4','eps') : 'q3'}

def epsilonClosure(transition, state):
    closure = []
    if (state, 'eps') not in transition:    # epsilon transition not possible
        return closure

    elif (state, 'eps') in transition:    # epsilon transition is possible
        closure.append(state)
        state = transition[(state, 'eps')]
        epsilonClosure(transition, state)

    if state not in closure:    # adds current state to list if not visited before
        closure.append(state)
    return closure

epsilonClosure(tf2, 'q1')
```

This code works for the non-list values in the dictionary but breaks when it hits a list.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

-edit
Fixed code so it was executable while isolated. Sorry!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with the output of running your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore the error for a moment and think in terms of the problem. Your function requires a name of a state as the value of the variable `state`. However, the list `['q2', 'q3']` is not a valid state. Rather each of the strings `'q2'` and `'q3'` are. You need to modify your algorithm to take this into account. I can think of two options:

1. Change the parameter list to accept a **list** of states. Then iterate over this list.
2. Change the recursive call to call the function for each state in the list.

If you have control over the dictionary input, I suggest that you use lists as all values. You can easily make a list with one state in it when needed. This will allow you to write your algorithm to always handle lists of state names.

If you are unable to do this, you will first have to check if the value from the dictionary is a list and treat it differently than if it is a string.

Comment: So I just tried doing the first thing and whenever I try to iterate over the lists using: "for x in state: " whenever I get to a list with just one state, the iteration is breaking up the string so it would iterate over each individual char.

Comment: @Luke be sure to read the second to last paragraph in my answer

Comment: I went back through my dictionary entries and made sure they were all in individual lists. I just ran some tests on my code and whenever I am iterating over a single state list outside of my function, it works as intended. It prints the one state. However, when I try to iterate inside of my function, the individual characters are passed in.

Comment: @Luke you are passing in a string as the state, not a list with the one state

Comment: my dictionary looks like this: `tf2 = {('q0','a') : ['q1'], ('q1','eps') : ['q2', 'q3'], ('q3','eps') : ['q0'], ('q2','a') : ['q4'], ('q4','eps') : ['q3']}` Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry! I just realized I was calling the function doing exactly what you were saying. I forgot to change my function call.